# New to Linux Nassing and File sharing

Tags: server, apache2, samba, ansible

So, I'm building my own tiny NAS. I have a question. I'd want to create a NAS (with SAMBA I'd say? OR whith Ansible NAS?),
which would have plex running (and  minecraft server ;)). Sometimes I'd want to share a file with a direct download link. Would this eb possible via SAMBA or do I need something like APACHE 2 for those things?

Vkr
Victor
ps: first time terminal Linux user, hehe, so scared a bit :)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04.1 LTS I'm planning on. I have the hardware on the way. So now it is software time ;)

Comment: if you want to share stuff you probably better install something like nextcloud...there are plenty of scripts for that